# Powershell exception when trying to start Usage Analytics

Tags: 2013, web-analytics, usage-counters

I am following the instructions detailed in this blog post [Usage analytics in SharePoint Server 2013](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2014/01/21/modify-the-content-search-web-part-display-template-and-use-windows-powershell-to-start-usage-analytics-in-sharepoint-server-2013.aspx), however when I attempt to start the Usage Analytics via Powershell I get an exception:

```
$a = Get-SPTimerJob -Type Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Analytics.AnalyticsJobDefinition
$sa = $a.GetAnalysis("Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Analytics.SearchAnalyticsJob")
$sa.StartAnalysis()
```

***Exception calling "StartAnalysis" with "0" argument(s): "No system manager locations set, search application might not be ready yet."***

[image]

How can I trigger the usage analytics process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a permissions issue.

The user I was logged on and running SharePoint Management Shell did not have access to the 'Search_Service_Application_' databases. When I allowed access for the user, the StartAnalysis() cmdlet executes successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to provision the Usage Application?

```
$usage = Get-SPServiceApplicationProxy | where {$_.TypeName -like "Usage*"}
$usage.Provision()
```

That is the most probable solution.

[This post](http://www.sharepointsecurity.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-development/no-system-manager-locations-set-search-application-might-not-be-ready-yet/) indicates it can also be a time mismatch problem:

> After looking at it for a while, it is because of a time skew between the VM server and the host machine. Do’h! So make sure that the time is synced between the two environments!

It can also be a side-effect of limiting how much memory `noderunner.exe` process is allowed to use, [read more here](http://www.sbrickey.com/Tech/Blog/Post/On_the_effects_of_memory_limiting_noderunner_exe).

Answer (score 0):

Do have a look at what robert has mentioned. Also, have you used the $sa object somewhere above those three lines of code in the same powershell window ? I have faced this similar issue of "**calling an X function with 0 parameters**" many times (but not with the same scenario of starting the usage analysis) and it turned out that you need to close the current powershell window, open a new one, run the commands and your code works !!

If you are running the powershell comman-by-command, try a fresh powershell window and all the commands in one go.